# Twitter4j search

Tags: java, search, twitter4j

I'm trying to search on twitter tweets. I use Twitter4j libs.
My problem is that i want to search for hashtags that also contains the specified word i search.
For example:
If i search **#hello** i would like my results to be:
**#hello
#helloworld
#hellothere
etc**

This is my code on the searchview:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query1)
                                            {



                                                return false;
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
                                            {
                                                if(!newText.startsWith("#"))
                                                {
                                                    newText = "#" + newText;
                                                }

                                                try {

                                                    Query query = new Query(newText);
                                                    query.setCount(100);

                                                    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

                                                    int c=1;

                                                    for(Status status: result.getTweets())
                                                    {
                                                        System.out.println("\nFor round:" + c+ "\nThe status is:"+ status.getText());
                                                        System.out.println("\n--------------");
                                                        System.out.println("\n-------Here are the hashtags for this post-------");


                                                        c++;
                                                    }
                                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
```

but when i type hello on my search bar,it only shows on my console (*i know i have to show them on screen*)tweets that have #hello as it is.

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to do this. However, if you have a limited selection of hashtags to search through you can try combining them into one query with an OR separator.